# Does JBOSS EAP 6.3 support spring + websocket?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websocket, jboss6.x

I am trying to implement websocket using JBOSS and I understand for enterprise edition  websockets are supported from JBOSS EAP 6.3. I am also trying to integrate websockets with spring. I was wondering, does JBOSS EAP 6.3 supports integration of websockets with spring?

I have followed and configured all the steps mentioned at

http://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

except that, the application is deployed in JBOSS EAP 6.3. When I execute and try to connect, I am hitting with the following error.

GET http://localhost:8080/hello/info 404 (Not Found)
  sockjs-0.3.4.min.js:27 u._startsockjs-0.3.4.min.js:27 (anonymous function)
  stomp.js:134 Whoops! Lost connection to undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Atmosphere Framework supports JBoss 6.3. Just take a look at this:

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Installing-JBoss-WebSocket-Support

Just jump on our mailing list for more information.

-- Jeanfrancois